# Vaadin-grid accessibility - Polymer

Tags: html, polymer, vaadin, polymer-2.x, vaadin-grid

Is there any way in which I can make my **`Vaadin-Grid`** accessible for screen reader users or even simply by tabbing? I'm thinking that only each row would need to be tabbed rather than each cell of each row. I also have a checkbox on each row, so that would also need consideration.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and please bare in mind that this is still a work in progress so I will be trying to add **`ARIA`** labels and things as I go.

[**Here is a JSBin with the actual code**](http://jsbin.com/himoyocice/edit?html,output)

**My `vaadin-grid` html**

```
<vaadin-grid aria-label="Server properties list" id="material" items="[[uksproperties]]">
    <vaadin-grid-selection-column width="66px" flex="0" select-all="{{selectAll}}">
        <template class="header">
            <paper-checkbox checked="{{selectAll}}"></paper-checkbox>
        </template>
        <template>
            <paper-checkbox checked="{{selected}}"></paper-checkbox>
        </template>
     </vaadin-grid-selection-column>
     <vaadin-grid-column>
         <template class="header">
            <div class="horizontal layout cell">
                <label for="keyFilter" class="keyText cell flex">Key</label>
                <vaadin-grid-filter class="cell" id="keyFilterVaadin" path="key" value="[[_filterKey]]">
                    <paper-input aria-describedby="keyDescription" no-float-label class="keyFilter" id="keyFilter" slot="filter" placeholder="Filter search" value="{{_filterKey::input}}"  focus-target on-input="clearAppear" >
                        <iron-icon suffix icon="clear" class="clearIcon" on-click="clearField" clear-item-id="keyFilter"></iron-icon>
                    </paper-input>
                    <span id="keyDescription" style="display:none" class="description">Input text to filter to properties list by "Key" search</span>
                </vaadin-grid-filter>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template class="cell"><div class="blue">[[item.key]]</div></template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>
    <vaadin-grid-column>
       <template class="header">
          <div class="cell">
            value
          <div>
        </template>
        <template class="cell">[[item.value]]</template>
    </vaadin-grid-column>
    <vaadin-grid-column>
        <template class="header">
            <div class="horizontal layout">
               <div class="cell last flex ">
                    Server
                </div>
                <paper-button slot="filter" class="export" on-click="empty">
                    <iron-icon icon="launch"></iron-icon>
                        Export
                </paper-button>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template class="cell last">[[item.server]]</template>
     </vaadin-grid-column>
 </vaadin-grid>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make a fiddle?

Comment: Sure thing @Ofisora. See my edited question for my JSBin version.

Answer (score 0):

What specific problem are you having with screen readers?

vaadin-grid should be mostly accessible out-of-the-box. Keyboard navigation is supported, and you can navigate the rows with the arrow keys. Just click a row/cell and start using the arrow keys to get the focus outline. You can also focus the grid with the Tab key – header, body and footer is focusable separately, not each row.

If you place focusable elements inside the cells (inputs, buttons, checkboxes, etc.) you need to press Enter to access those, as specified in the WAI-ARIA best practices for data grids.